# PyQT signal connection with extra information using Lambda is not working correctly

Tags: python, signals, pyqt6

I'm running a simple code to creat 4 checkboxes in a widget
I have a simple function to change the checkbox text when clicked based on wheater it's checked or not

I'm trying to connect the "clicked" signal to slot "on_checkBox_ss" using Lambda method to pass an extar parameter to identify the clicked checkbox

but it's not working well, it pass False/True instead of the checkbox index

here is the code

```
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QCheckBox, QApplication, QVBoxLayout

class mainwidget():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        vlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.CHK_BoxGRP = [checkBoxClass(self.widget,f"ChkBox_{x}") for x in range(0,4)]
        [vlayout.addWidget(self.CHK_BoxGRP[i].chkbox) for i in range(0,4)]
        
        # Build the connection
        [self.CHK_BoxGRP[y].chkbox.clicked.connect(lambda y:self.on_checkBox_ss(y)) for 
        y in range (0,4)]
  
    #function to process the clicked checkbox
    def on_checkBox_ss(self,boxnum):
        if self.CHK_BoxGRP[boxnum].chkbox.isChecked():
            self.CHK_BoxGRP[boxnum].chkbox.setText("Clicked")
        else:
            self.CHK_BoxGRP[boxnum].chkbox.setText("Not Clicked")

"""  Below is check box class """
class checkBoxClass:
    
    def __init__(self,PARENT,CHKLABEL) -> None:
        #super().__init__()
        self.parent = PARENT
        self.chkLabel = CHKLABEL
        #self.operat_on = OPERAT_ON
        
        self.chkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.parent)
        self.chkbox.setStyleSheet("border-color: rgb(85, 85, 255);")
        self.chkbox.setObjectName(self.chkLabel)
        self.chkbox.setChecked(True)
        self.chkbox.setText(f"GROUP {self.chkLabel[-1]}")


""" start of main code"""        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = mainwidget()
    
    mainwindow.widget.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Don't use list comprehension for that, it's bad practice. They don't provide absolutely ***any*** benefit (on the contrary, they are more costly than a standard for loop since they also create a list for that loop), and they just make your code less readable and much more difficult to debug.

Comment: i tried it with a normal for loop but faced the same problem, as @Atalay mentioned below,
the issue is about signal default argument passed to the slot

Comment: @mabdeltaweb I was *not* referring to the lambda issue (which wouldn't obviously change anything). My comment was about *generic usage*: use list comprehension only when it really makes sense. If you're using it to make one-liner calls in a loop (as in you also did for the layout's `addWidget()`), then just *don't*: it may look cool, but it's not; as said, there's absolutely ***no*** benefit, doing it is just a terrible idea for performance (it creates a list that'll immediately be thrown away), readability (you get long lines with cryptic code) and debugging (you cannot put print statements).

Comment: got it, I tried it in another code and used debugger it was behaving in a very confusing way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QPushButton.clicked.connect() method automatically passes the state of the button (bool) as default first argument, so if there is only one argument -which is 'y' in comprehension in this case- is overwritten with the state of the button.

You can see that if you just print(boxnum) in 'on_checkBox_ss', it prints out True or False which is the state of clicked button, and by coincidence list[True] will return #1 index and list[False] will return #0 (as it should be because boolean expressions are just 0 or 1 at the end of the day)

I said that this was a coincidence because your code actually works (just not the way as intended) and doesn't give an error which make it seem like the problem has something to do with signals and loops in the framework.

So the solution is to overwrite the state argument with anything (which will be 'x' -or anything for that matter) and pass 'y' explicitly.

```
[self.CHK_BoxGRP[y].chkbox.clicked.connect(lambda x="", y=y: self.on_checkBox_ss(y)) for y in range(4)]
```

So it will be:

```
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QCheckBox, QApplication, QVBoxLayout

class mainwidget():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        vlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.CHK_BoxGRP = [checkBoxClass(self.widget,f"ChkBox_{x}") for x in range(0,4)]
        [vlayout.addWidget(self.CHK_BoxGRP[i].chkbox) for i in range(0,4)]
        
        # Build the connection
        #[self.CHK_BoxGRP[y].chkbox.clicked.connect(lambda y:self.on_checkBox_ss(y)) for 
        #y in range (0,4)]
        
        [self.CHK_BoxGRP[y].chkbox.clicked.connect(lambda x="", y=y:self.on_checkBox_ss(y)) for y in range(4)]

  
    #function to process the clicked checkbox
    def on_checkBox_ss(self,boxnum):
        print(boxnum) # now prints out actual y value instead of True or False
        if self.CHK_BoxGRP[boxnum].chkbox.isChecked():
            self.CHK_BoxGRP[boxnum].chkbox.setText("Clicked")
        else:
            self.CHK_BoxGRP[boxnum].chkbox.setText("Not Clicked")

"""  Below is check box class """
class checkBoxClass:
    
    def __init__(self,PARENT,CHKLABEL) -> None:
        #super().__init__()
        self.parent = PARENT
        self.chkLabel = CHKLABEL
        #self.operat_on = OPERAT_ON
        
        self.chkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.parent)
        self.chkbox.setStyleSheet("border-color: rgb(85, 85, 255);")
        self.chkbox.setObjectName(self.chkLabel)
        self.chkbox.setChecked(True)
        self.chkbox.setText(f"GROUP {self.chkLabel[-1]}")


""" start of main code"""        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = mainwidget()
    
    mainwindow.widget.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: I got your point, so the dummy x argument in Lambda will absorb the default argument from the signal. it is now working fine

Comment: @mabdeltawab if this answer solved your issue, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the gray tick mark on its left.